# Orchard CMS: Weird time stamp behavior

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

When I post an article i noticed that whenever I publish a post before 8am (I've set the site to GMT +8), the date of the said article will always be dd-1, which will in turn affect the routing. My server is on Arvixe. How can I resolve this without modifying code?

Comment: Which date? Looks like you're using a UTC date in your autoroute pattern.

Comment: {Content.Container.Path}/{Content.Date.Format:yyyy}/{Content.Date.Format:MM}/{Co‌​ntent.Date.Format:dd}/{Content.Slug}

the day will always be -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Date tokens, all values are in UTC by default. You can get the local value by appending `.Local` like this:

```
{Date.Local}
```

or with formatting options:

```
{Date.Local.Format:yyyy/MM/dd}
```

In the case of the creation date for a content item:

```
{Content.Date.Local.Format:yyyy/MM/dd}
```